# toggle not staying open in IE

Tags: javascript

I have this code to toggle the panel div which works fine however whithin it are reg & login forms, when error text is generated and the page reloads i want the toggle to stay open... it does in all browsers apart from IE is there a fix for this?

```
     <% if errTxt_slide > "" or errTxt_lin > "" then %>
     <script language="javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;    
     });
```

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing more code, I would guess that jQuery is unsure of what `$(this)` is.  Are you able to reference the `id` or some other identifier for `div`?  For instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#panel").toggleClass("active"); 
});
```

Note that I also removed the `return false;` as I see no need for it in the above code.  You code will simply run when the page is loaded.  It does not need to return anything.

Comment: Great thank you very much it works a treat in all browsers, thanks again great help.